# Proper caching frequently used data

Tags: mongodb, caching, redis, backend

**not quite sure if this question is good to ask on Stackoverflow or not.**

Im currently creating a webpage that would use Mongodb logic, and redis. ( with node.js )

when user are on a page, the backend will get asked to get their user details every 5 seconds.

when retrieving this that frequently, should i get it / store it in the redis, or the mongoDB? need it for some sort of caching.

the reason is that its every 5 sec, is because it could be some changes to it that needs to be reflected backend.

each user would have their details as `username`, `password`,  `money`, and 25 other values.

How should i approach this, to make less heavy if i were just using MongoDB alone?

example:

```
function calledEvery5Sec(userid) {
 // get from Mongodb...
}
```

or

```
function CalledEverySec(userid) {
// get from redis if its avaliable there, else load from mongodb).
}
```

Comment: If you search by `indexed fields`, [MongoDB serves from RAM (cache)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-handle-caching)

Answer (score 0):

Use TTL index for the fields you want to store for a short period of time 
For that using $out or $merge create a new tmp collection and fetch details from it .

Can you post sample document.

Comment: problem im gonna possibly change those values every few mins. + its needed to be reflected every 4 sec or so.